# Datas from sensor to website or mobile application

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cloud, iot, sensors

I'm new to this computer science and coding since I'm from mechanical background. Actually I'm under going an project in which I need to sense data from sensor using raspberry pi. I need to send those data to cloud database or any other database and then I should make them to see in website or mobile application? 
Is this possible? If possible, what should I learn for this long process? Please tell me the process involved?
Currently I'm learning Python (django) and mySQL what should I learn more? 
Actually this is an IOT project! 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has excellent [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-python) on Raspberry Pi and Azure IoT hub.
You can proceed through these tutorials until sending stream data to Power Bi which is an interactive data visualization tool (supports displaying on mobile devices), so you don't need to create a website.

Also, you may get stuck on reading analog sensors data on Raspberry Pi. I may go deeper, but not sure you need information about the mechanical part there.

Answer (score 0):

---

You can see the Microsoft Documentation regarding Azure IoT Hub which provides step by step guide on how to install it using Raspberry Pi's command line. It also provides a virtual setup of a sensor on how to get its data to the IoT Hub panel plus getting data on Visual Studio Code extension: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33355711)